# JS function 'not defined' after adding for loop

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop

I'm trying to create a calculator that takes a number as input, decides in which range this number is, and adds a corresponding price to the basic price (currently set to 0).
However, I'm stuck at a rather simple for-loop I inserted to iterate over the ranges (in seizprijs). Without the for-loop, the code appears to do just fine. However, if I run the code including the for-loop, the function returns 'not defined'.

I'm completely new to coding, so I expect it to be a simple issue. However, I tried every suggestion I could find online, and nothing seems to work.

```js
const seizprijs = [
{tijd : "winter", bdatum : 1, edatum : 5, prijs : 45},
{tijd: "lente", bdatum: 5, edatum: 9, prijs: 50}
];

function myFunction() {
  var prijs = 0;

  var vdat = document.getElementById("datum");
  var vdatum = vdat.value;

  for (var x = 0, x < seizprijs.length, x++){

    if (vdatum > seizprijs[1].bdatum && vdatum < seizprijs[1].edatum)
    {
      prijs += seizprijs[1].prijs;
    }
  }

 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Totaalprijs:" + prijs;

}
```

```html
<h1>Boeking</h1>
<p id="demo">Totaalprijs: </p>
<form id="boeking">
  <input type="number" name="datum" id="datum">
</form>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Prijs berekenen</button>
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp
for (var x = 0; x < seizprijs.length; x++)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using `,` instead of `;` in your for loop

try like this

```
for (var x = 0; x < seizprijs.length; x++)
```

Comment: Thanks, that was it! I changed that around before, but apparently made another mistake at first, and didn't change it back. It works now! :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be the data type of the value from the input. Use `+` unary operator to convert the string to number. Also if you are iterating a loop use the `index` , `x` in your code to access the value from the array of object

```js
const seizprijs = [{
    tijd: "winter",
    bdatum: 1,
    edatum: 5,
    prijs: 45
  },
  {
    tijd: "lente",
    bdatum: 5,
    edatum: 9,
    prijs: 50
  }
];

function myFunction() {
  var prijs = 0;

  var vdat = document.getElementById("datum");
  var vdatum = +vdat.value;

  for (var x = 0; x < seizprijs.length; x++) {

    if (vdatum > seizprijs[x].bdatum && vdatum < seizprijs[x].edatum) {
      prijs += seizprijs[x].prijs;
    }
  }

  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Totaalprijs:" + prijs;

}
```

```html
<h1>Boeking</h1>
<p id="demo">Totaalprijs: </p>
<form id="boeking">
  <input type="number" name="datum" id="datum">
</form>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Prijs berekenen</button>
```